# Select different rows from two tables based on multiple fields

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need to select rows from one table which do not exist in another table. However, I can't join on the `ID` because the tables are from different databases.

In first database, I have table a table named `Actual`:
[image]

And the second table from different database is named `Forecasts`:
[image]

I have a context for each database and use the following C# code to get the data:

```cs
var forecastRows = targetContext.Forecasts.ToList();
var actualRows = sourceContext.Actual.ToList()
    .Select(actual => new
    {
        TargetMonth = DateTimeExtensions.GetMonthCode(actual.Date.Year, actual.Date.Month),
        CustomerCode = actual.CustomerGroupNo,
        actual.Brand
    });
```

Then I define variable to get rows from `Forecasts` table, which do not exist in the `Actual` table:

```cs
var orphanActualRows = forecastRows.Where(row => 
    !actualRows.Any(f => f.Brand == row.Brand.Code 
                      && f.CustomerCode == row.Customer.Code 
                      && f.TargetMonth == row.TargetMonth));
```

But it doesn't works correctly. It returns the total count of the `Forecasts` table. But it isn't accurate because the row count is much less...

Comment: Don't post code as images here, it is generally frowned upon.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius And [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4416750) is a good list of reasons why not to do this.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius, еdited question as you recommended, thanks, but it would be better if you'll help me :)

Comment: Your question doesnt make much sense so you need to help us to help you first.

Comment: Wild guess here, but to ensure `row.Brand` and `row.Customer` are available you should force an `Include` while retrieving the forecast data: `var forecastRows = targetContext.Forecasts.Include("Customer").ToList();`

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius and what i need to explain? I provided my tables, and code i have a problem with. You can ask what you need to help me and not abstract answers...

Comment: Apparently you're not getting null reference exceptions at `row.Brand.Code` and `row.Customer.Code`, but are you sure they are equal? No case differences, no leading/trailing spaces?

Comment: Your last two lines are completely unclear and possibly contradictory. There is no count shown in the code, so what do you mean by "returns the total count". And what row count is much less than what?

Answer (score -1):

i think this join can help you.

```
  var orpahanActualRows = targetContext.Forecast.Join(
            sourceContext.Actual,
            forecastRows => new { forecastRows.Brand, forecastRows.CustomerCode, forecastRows.TargetMonth },
            actualRows => new { actualRows.Brand, actualRows.CustomerGroupNo, actualRows.Date.Year, actualRows.Date.Month},
            (forecastRows, actualRows) => new { f = forecastRows,  rows=actualRows })
            .Where(d => d.rows.Brand.Code != d.f.Brand
                    && d.rows.CustomerCode != d.f.CustomerCode
                    && rows.TargetMonth != DateTimeExtensions.GetMonthCode(rows.Date.Year, rows.Date.Month))
            .Select(d => d.f)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Your method looks good but it has a lot of syntax error like alone ')' before }.
I'm new in c# and can't get it over with alone. If you could can you fix it?

Comment: This is incorrect code. The join keys don't match. And it doesn't make any sense, because you're  joining and then you filter the rows that *don't* join.

Comment: Yes, this code only works If the FK's are in the tables and imported in the EF. That's important.